# Python CSV: commas, single and double quotes inside columns

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write csv file using DictWriter but columns like this:

> 2,2',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine

breakes everything. The header is:

```
"#","Index no.","EC / List no.","CAS no.","Name","Page ID","Link"
```

And column above should be in column Name, but here what I got when I'm trying to write this row:

```
OrderedDict([('\ufeff "#"', '756'), ('Index no.', '613-114-00-6'), 
             ('EC / List no.', '225-208-0'), ('CAS no.', '4719-04-4'),
             # most of the following should be the value to 'Name' 
             # `PageId` should be '122039' and 'Link' should be the 'https...' text
             ('Name', "2,2',2-(hexahydro-1"), ('Page ID', '3'), 
             ('Link', '5-triazine-1'), 
             (None, ['3', '5-triyl)triethanol|1', '3', 
                     '5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1', '3', 
                     '5-triazine"', '122039',
                     'https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039'])
```

I tried every possible combination of DictWriter parameters

```
quotechar='"', doublequote=False, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar='\\'
```

and nothing helped.

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

old.csv

```
"#","Index no.","EC / List no.","CAS no.","Name","Page ID"
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","2,2',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine","122039"
```

code:

```
import csv

    with open('old.csv') as f, open('new.csv', 'w') as ff:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            result = csv.DictWriter(ff, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
            for line in reader:
                result.writerow(line)
```

Comment: What format do you expect as output? `doublequote=False` looks wrong for most CSV dialects, but what you expect and need depends on whatever is supposed to be reading this output. Do you target a particular consumer? Can you find documentation for its behavior?

Comment: I tried just to  print reader line and it's already has a problem, so I probably need to add some parameters to DictReader.

Comment: Adding parameters will not work -your csv data is badly formatted - it does not escape `"` correctly. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **old.csv** is badly formatted - it does not escape `"` (nor doubles it) correctly:

```
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","2,2',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine","122039"
----------------------------------------------------^ here is the not escaped "
```

This line should look like:

```
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","2,2',2\"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine","122039","https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039"
----------------------------------------------------^^ escaped "
```

Using `doublequote=True` would need the `"` inside a field to be doubled up: `"tata""tata"` for `tata"tata` - your source data does neither: doubling up nor escaping.

---

This works flawlessly:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

fieldn = ["#","Index no.","EC / List no.","CAS no.","Name","Page ID","Link"]
od = OrderedDict(
    [('#', '756'), ('Index no.', '613-114-00-6'), 
     ('EC / List no.', '225-208-0'), ('CAS no.', '4719-04-4'),
     ('Name', '''2,2',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine'''), 
     ('Page ID', '122039'), 
     ('Link', 'https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039')])

print(od)  # see: Input to writer:

import csv 

# write the ordered dict    
with open("file.txt", "w",newline = "") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, quotechar='"', doublequote=False, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar= '\\', fieldnames=fieldn)
    writer.writeheader()  # remove if you do not want the header in as well
    writer.writerow(od)

# read it back in and print it
with open ("file.txt") as r:
    reader = csv.DictReader(r, quotechar='"', doublequote=False, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True, escapechar= '\\', fieldnames=fieldn)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)        # see Output after reading in written stuff
```

Input to writer:

```
OrderedDict([('#', '756'), ('Index no.', '613-114-00-6'), ('EC / List no.', '225-208-0'), ('CAS no.', '4719-04-4'), ('Name', '2,2\',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine'), ('Page ID', '122039'), ('Link', 'https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039')])
```

Output after reading in written stuff (writes header as well - hence the double output):

```
OrderedDict([('#', '#'), ('Index no.', 'Index no.'), ('EC / List no.', 'EC / List no.'), ('CAS no.', 'CAS no.'), ('Name', 'Name'), ('Page ID', 'Page ID'), ('Link', 'Link')])
OrderedDict([('#', '756'), ('Index no.', '613-114-00-6'), ('EC / List no.', '225-208-0'), ('CAS no.', '4719-04-4'), ('Name', '2,2\',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine'), ('Page ID', '122039'), ('Link', 'https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039')])
```

File content:

```
"#","Index no.","EC / List no.","CAS no.","Name","Page ID","Link"
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","2,2',2\"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine","122039","https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals/cl-inventory-database/-/discli/details/122039"
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your answer. How can I add escape character to input file? I have hundreds of csv files with hundreds of rows like this.

Comment: @NoG Go to the source and let them fix it. If you can't and the amount of columns is fixed and you know this error can only happen inside `"Name"` you could write a python program that somehow "fixes" this error. That would be a totally different problem / question though. You can read each file line-wise, split it and check if it has more then the allowed columns, if so you would have to use some smart code to fix the error and write a corrected file. You might simply check each "row" for its length and report the "bad" into an error file and fix them by hand if the good/bad ratio is okish.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* only the 5th column has double quotes in the data and the other columns are quoted correctly as shown, you could use a regular expression to capture the columns and re-write the CSV:

**bad.csv**

```
"#","Index no.","EC / List no.","CAS no.","Name","Page ID"
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","2,2',2"-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine","122039"
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4",""Example"","122039"
"756","613-114-00-6","225-208-0","4719-04-4","Another "example" of bad formatting","122039"
```

**test.py**

```
import re
import csv

with open('bad.csv') as fin:
    with open('good.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for line in fin:
            items = re.match(r'"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*)","(.*?)"$',line).groups()
            writer.writerow(items)
```

**good.csv**

```
#,Index no.,EC / List no.,CAS no.,Name,Page ID
756,613-114-00-6,225-208-0,4719-04-4,"2,2',2""-(hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine-1,3,5-triyl)triethanol|1,3,5-tris(2-hydroxyethyl)hexahydro-1,3,5-triazine",122039
756,613-114-00-6,225-208-0,4719-04-4,"""Example""",122039
756,613-114-00-6,225-208-0,4719-04-4,"Another ""example"" of bad formatting",122039
```